# Regex: start with something and ends with whatever except something

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I need a regex for Url rewrite module, to validate urls in such way:

1) spa/          - match

2) spa/some/url  - match

3) spa/some-url  - match

4) spa/some.js   - no match

5) spa/some.css  - no match

So, it should match, if url 
a) starts with "spa"
b) ends with whatever except ".js" or ".css"

What I tried to test is ^(spa/)((?!.js)|(?!.css))$
but it's not working.

Thank you and sorry if it's duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

`^spa\/((.+)\/)*.*(?<!\.js|\.css)$`

with g and m flags set.

Please note that this regex allows several characters that urls are not supposed to have. I have tried to keep it simple. So, you might want to tune it a bit before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need [negative-lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this.

Try this (you may need to modify it slightly)

```
^spa.*(?<!(\.js|\.css))$
```

- `^spa` : string beginning with `spa`
- `.*` : followed by any character(s)
- `(?<!(\.js|\.css))$` : not ending with `.js` or `.css`